# Apache Kafka-Log4j-Appender not working spark cluster mode

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, log4j2

I try to sends my spark application driver/executor logs to kafka topic. It is working in Eclipse.
While deploying cluster mode it is showing

> ClassNotFoundException.

I added `spark core`, `spark-sql`, `spark stream kafka`, `spark streaming`, `kafka streaming` and `kafka-log4j-appender` maven's but still it is showing

> org.apche.kafka.log4jappender ClassNotFoundException.

In server there is no kafka related jars available in my spark program running jar have itself.

Please anyone tell why it is not sending logs to kafka topic from spark driver/executor in cluster mode.

i tried the below link mentioned steps also,

[spark streaming application and kafka log4j appender issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36158722/spark-streaming-application-and-kafka-log4j-appender-issue)

```
og4j.rootLogger=INFO, console, KAFKA, file

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n
log4j.appender.KAFKA=org.apache.kafka.log4jappender.KafkaLog4jAppender
log4j.appender.KAFKA.topic=test2
log4j.appender.KAFKA.name=localhost
log4j.appender.KAFKA.host=localhost
log4j.appender.KAFKA.port=9092
log4j.appender.KAFKA.brokerList=localhost:9092
log4j.appender.KAFKA.compressionType=none
log4j.appender.KAFKA.requiredNumAcks=0
log4j.appender.KAFKA.syncSend=true
log4j.appender.KAFKA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.KAFKA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L %% - %m%n
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=log4j-application.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB``
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-M` `M-dd` ` HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n` `
```

How to send spark driver/executor logs to kafka topic via kafka-log4j-appender-2.3.0 using log4j.properties.

Answer (score 0):

## kafka-log4j-appender with Spark

I managed to use `spark-submit 2.1.1` in `cluster` mode with `kafka-log4j-appender 2.3.0`, but I believe other versions will behave similarly.

---

### Provide `kafka-log4j-appender` for Spark

Basically, `spark` is missing `kafka-log4j-appender`.

Generally, you should be able to provide `kafka-log4j-appender` in your fat jar. I had some previous experience with [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45480145/1549135) where it does not work. Simply because in a cluster environment your classpath is overridden by Spark. So if it does not work for you either, move on.

#### Option A. Manually download jars:

```
kafka-log4j-appender-2.3.0.jar
kafka-clients-2.3.0.jar
```

You actually need both, because appender won't work without clients. 
Place them on the same machine you fire `spark-submit` from. 
The benefit is, that you can name them as you like.

Now for `client` mode

```
JARS='/absolute/path/kafka-log4j-appender-2.3.0.jar,/absolute/path/kafka-clients-2.3.0.jar'
JARS_CLP='/absolute/path/kafka-log4j-appender-2.3.0.jar:/absolute/path/kafka-clients-2.3.0.jar'
JARS_NAMES='kafka-log4j-appender-2.3.0.jar:kafka-clients-2.3.0.jar'

spark-submit \
    --deploy-mode client \
    --jars "$JARS"
    --conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=$JARS_CLP" \
    --conf "spark.executor.extraClassPath=$JARS_NAMES" \
```

Or for `cluster` mode

```
spark-submit \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --jars "$JARS"
    --conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=$JARS_NAMES" \
    --conf "spark.executor.extraClassPath=$JARS_NAMES" \
```

#### Option B. Use `--packages` to download jars from maven:

I think this is more convenient, but you have to get the name precisely.

You need to look for those kinds of lines during run:

```
19/11/15 19:44:08 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/srv/cortb/home/atais/.ivy2/jars/org.apache.kafka_kafka-log4j-appender-2.3.0.jar -> hdfs:///user/atais/.sparkStaging/application_1569430771458_10776/org.apache.kafka_kafka-log4j-appender-2.3.0.jar
19/11/15 19:44:08 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/srv/cortb/home/atais/.ivy2/jars/org.apache.kafka_kafka-clients-2.3.0.jar -> hdfs:///user/atais/.sparkStaging/application_1569430771458_10776/org.apache.kafka_kafka-clients-2.3.0.jar
```

and note down how the `jars` are called inside `application_1569430771458_10776` folder on `hdfs`.

Now for `client` mode

```
JARS_CLP='/srv/cortb/home/atais/.ivy2/jars/org.apache.kafka_kafka-log4j-appender-2.3.0.jar:/srv/cortb/home/atais/.ivy2/jars/org.apache.kafka_kafka-clients-2.3.0.jar'
KAFKA_JARS='org.apache.kafka_kafka-log4j-appender-2.3.0.jar:org.apache.kafka_kafka-clients-2.3.0.jar'

spark-submit \
    --deploy-mode client \
    --packages "org.apache.kafka:kafka-log4j-appender:2.3.0"
    --conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=$JARS_CLP" \
    --conf "spark.executor.extraClassPath=$KAFKA_JARS" \
```

Or for `cluster` mode

```
spark-submit \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --packages "org.apache.kafka:kafka-log4j-appender:2.3.0"
    --conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=$KAFKA_JARS" \
    --conf "spark.executor.extraClassPath=$KAFKA_JARS" \
```

---

### The above should work already

### Extra steps

If you want to provide your `logging.proprietes`, follow my tutorial on that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55596389/1549135